# how to escape empty lines from end of command result

Tags: parsing, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

i use the following command to create a variable from my CPU Name:

```
@echo off
Rem create variable from cpu name
for /f "useback tokens=* skip=1" %%g in (`wmic cpu get name ^|findstr /i "."`) do (
    set CPU_NAME=%%g
    echo %CPU_NAME%
)
```

but the result is nothing, because there is some empty lines at end of "`wmic cpu get name`" command result and remove created variable

how can i solve it?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There are some empty lines at the end of `wmic cpu get name`

Use findstr as follows to strip blank lines from the wmic output. You also need to use delayed expansion

Corrected batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Rem create variable from cpu name
for /f "useback tokens=* skip=1" %%g in (`wmic cpu get name ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
    set CPU_NAME=%%g
    echo !CPU_NAME!
  )
endlocal
```

Example usage:

```
> test
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, its what really i looking for, your great!

Answer (score 4):

Please search SO for `delayed expansion`.

```
call echo %%CPU_NAME%%
```

should show you the required data. This is one of several well-documented solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to echo the result within the for loop in your case because you are only setting a single name. Just echo it later.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC CPU Get Name'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "CPU_NAME=%%B"
Echo=%CPU_NAME%
```

The second For loop is intended to remove the unwanted 'empty lines' you reported.